# docker compose down service with label

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically compose down several services with a label.

Currently I'm just using `docker container stop` as such: `docker container stop -t 60 $(docker ps -q -f "label=backup")`

I've tried `docker compose --project-directory /mnt/docker/HDA down $(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" -f "label=backup")` but unfortunately container names aren't the service names.

Is there any way of extracting the service names with the labels at all that anyone knows of? I'm a bit stuck.